# Google Tag Manager is hiding my custom HTML tag with css

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I have added a custom HTML tag which is being triggered by a dataLayer variable. Everything is showing up on the page but for some reason my entire custom html tag code is wrapped in a div that hides everything:

```
<div style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
                <div id="newsletter" class="animated animatedvisible rubberBand">
                    <h3>Dynamic Drive Newsletter</h3>
                    <p>Sign up for our FREE newsletter to get early access to new scripts!</p>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL">
                        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
                    </form>
                    <span class="scrollboxclose" onclick="scrollbox1.hide()">x</span>
                </div>

                <div id="specialoffer" class="animated">
                    <b>DDWhois</b> Free Domain Whois and Research Tool. Always free, always anonymous. <button onclick="location='http://ddwhois.com'">Visit</button>
                    <span class="scrollboxclose" onclick="scrollbox2.hide()">x</span>
                </div>

                <script>var scrollbox1=new scrollBox({elementid:"newsletter",dir:"down"}),scrollbox2=new scrollBox({elementid:"specialoffer",dir:"up",fxclass:"slideInDown",pctboundary:50});</script></div>
```

`<div style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">` is not part of the code I added to my tag.

There is a [JS script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/ddscrollbox.js) that makes the custom html code work but I didn't see anything in it that would insert the extra div

Comment: I'm not sure why GTM is doing that. In your snippet, you can add some JS that removes the styles. `document.getElementById('newsletter').parentElement.removeAttribute('style')`

Comment: Thanks. That worked like a charm. Now I need to figure out why GTM is doing it!

Comment: Tangentially related topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608165/why-google-tag-manager-puts-both-displaynone-and-visibilityhidden-on-iframe

Comment: @nyuen I looked at that post first. Seems like they are just discussing the redundancy of doing display:none and visibility but not the why.

Comment: GTM isn't a content management system, maybe thats why?

Comment: @michaelsinner Thanks for your very useful comment.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this by turning off the option: "Support document.write" on the Custom HTML tag configuration.

Comment: Yes, for some reason it makes the assumption that by checking document.write enabled, you are going to insert ALL your markup via script. Annoying. You really helped me out here, Luke on a late night coding. Really appreciate you sharing.